# Get scan code from WM_CHAR message

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, scancodes

How can I convert a character of any language that I catch via `WM_CHAR` in `WndProc` to a keyboard scan code? Like if the button pressed is `x` it would return 0x2d and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scan code is in bits 16-23 of the lParam parameter according to the [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, so just shift and mask:

```
int scanCode = (lParam >> 16) & 0xff;
```

If you've got a character you can call [OemKeyScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which puts the scan code in the low byte:

```
char c='X';
int scanCode=OemKeyScan(c) & 0x0ff;
```

Comment: But how to do it if there is no lParam (if it is not in WndProc)? How to convert char to scan code?

Comment: There is always an `lParam` in your WndProc (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx). You can you're catching via WM_CHAR so just look at the parameter.

Comment: I mean if i get the char in std::getchar(). Not in WndProc. In WndProc works fine

Comment: @Romka - can't you just cast the `char` to an `int` ?

Comment: It won't work, because casted char 'x' to int is 120, not 0x2d(45)

Comment: Do you have an ideas how to convert?